# FIFOS between PHP and C

Tags: php, c, ipc, fifo, mkfifo

I want to communicate 2 process using FIFOS. One process is writting in C and the other in PHP. The problem is that if I use FIFOS, the writer blocks until the reader open the FIFO, and the same in the other direction.
I explain it better, I have a PHP process that recieve xml request. The PHP take the xml and send it to the FIFO1(conecting with the C process). The C process read the FIFO1 takes the xml do some stuff and send the response to the FIFO2(connecting with the PHP). I want to do it in non-block. I mean, if the PHP process cannot read anything from the FIFO2 it no blocks and it can receive xml request meanwhile.
If there is someone interested I can post my code here.

Thanks ;).

Comment: as you know, `FIFO` is just name of data structure. what kind of `FIFO` do you want? PIPE?

Comment: Yes. Is commonly named FIFOS(NAMED PIPES).

Comment: what about `popen()` simple but one way("r" or "w")

Comment: Should your PHP application process XML synchronous? I mean, does PHP process that receives the xml care about processing? If it doesn't, you may process different queues with different PHP processes so it wouldn't block each other

Comment: No Is the same PHP process. I mean, the PHP do two things,look if some xml arrive from the server, if there aren´t any xml request, look if there are some information on the FIFO2 with the C process. The problem is that the PHP blocks when I read from the FIFO2.

Comment: Hi finally I decided to use shockets for communitation between php and c, so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a stream to non-blocking in PHP.

```
$resource = fopen('...', 'r');
stream_set_blocking($resource, 0);
```